# browser is not defined - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, browser

I am having a problem with the Chrome browser and not Firefox.

> Paused on exception ReferenceError: browser is not defined
>
> ReferenceError: browser is not defined at shouldWrapAPIs
> (polyfill.js:228) at polyfill.js:250

I can’t identify the cause of the problem, only that it happens in Chrome and not Firefox.

Could someone give me some help indicating what causes that problem?

It shows me in polyfill.js the following.
indicating precisely the following line

> return !(browser.storage.local.get() instanceof Promise);

```
function shouldWrapAPIs()
{
try
{
return !(browser.storage.local.get() instanceof Promise);
}
catch (error)
{
}

return true;
}
```

As indicated by error in the line return! (Browser.storage.local.get () instanceof Promise); I consider that it is an error that possibly comes from saving or storing data in the browser.

I save data in the browser with the following API.

```
export async function setItem(key: string, value: any) {
  await Storage.set({
    key: key,
    value: value
  });
}

export async function getItem(key: string) : Promise<any>{
  const { value } = await Storage.get({ key: key});
  return value;
}
export async function removeItem(key: string) {
  await Storage.remove({ key: key });
}
```

Is it possible that the problem comes from there?

I use the API for example as shown in the following code:

```
  axios.get(url+"1"+"/"+user+"/"+email)
  .then((res: { data: any; }) => {
    const resquest = res.data;
    console.log(res.data)
    if(resquest==="User alredy taken"){
      onShowAlert();
    }
    else{
        setItem("isRegistered", user );
        setItem("infoCompleted", false);
        setItem("clientType", "1");
        setCount(5);
    }
  })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem was fixed by disabling Adblock

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses property `chrome.storage`

Here is an article explaining this - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I want the application to be cross-platform and run the same in all browsers.

Comment: @JAOdev I'm not a master in this, but I think that your app needs to detect which browser it is using and after that change ```browser``` variable  based on which browser user is loading it. All I could find is this article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: The problem was fixed by disabling Adblock

Comment: Didn't expect this haha.
Thanks for letting me know